# Documentation at the top level of a GraphQL schema

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm documenting all my types, fields and parameters in my schema (SDL), including `Query` and `Mutation` at the top - but I can't work out how to add a single piece of documentation for the top-level of the whole schema.

I'm not sure if it's the spec or the tooling - Apollo for example allows me to write `schema { }`, but not to put anything inside it, or documentation before it.

And there are no examples of it in the docs, particularly at https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Descriptions, which shows a "well-described" schema without a top-top-level doc string.

Is this something the spec doesn't cover, or just the tooling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike types, the `SchemaDefinition` [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#SchemaDefinition) does not contain a `Description`. The `__Schema` [introspection type](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Schema-Introspection) also does not have a `description` field. So there is no way to set or get a description for the entire schema.

It is, however, an [upcoming feature](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/pull/466).